# D3.js X axis line not displaying

Tags: d3.js

In the example of bivariate chart (mbostock’s block #3884914), x-axis line is not visible. I tried in different ways but could not make the line appear. What can i do to make the line appear? Only ticks are available in the example.

Link : http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3884914

Answer (score 6, accepted):

this is the css rule, that is responsible for hiding x-axis ,, you need to remove it from the code and it will appear

```
.x.axis path {
  display: none;
}
```